# 3D PointCloud Particle System does not show any particles, unless the camera can see the coordinate origin. Math or JS error?

Tags: javascript, graphics, 3d, three.js

Thank you for having a look at my problem. Currently I am working on a university project and have reached a problem that I can't seem to solve. I narrowed down where the mistake most likely occurs, but I am still a little clueless. I'm going to explain my situation below:

This is a 3D space ship shooter, that we are building using three.js. I am trying to create a ray of particles, that I want to use as an afterburner effect for the space ship.

The first step was to write a particle renderer. The particle renderer has an update function that periodically updates the particles themselves, as well as the start and end point of the particle ray. So in each update call, after a possible movement of the spaceship, I want to calculate the new start and end point of the particle ray.

The particle renderer itself works perfectly fine in a test environment, however using it in the real program I encountered a weird bug: The particle ray works just fine, as long as the coordinate origin is visible for the camera. If the camera cannot see the origin, the particles appear to be invisible. One possible error might be, that the system actually works but the particles are rendered in a different position? Seems very unlikely though, since for the most part the program logic is fine.

I am going to post the code below, that updates the position of the ship. In case more code is needed, please feel free to comment below or ask me directly. I can send you the link to the git repository, however, since it is a public repository of my university group I am not comfortable posting the whole code publically. Thank you for understanding.

```
// this is the update function that is called in each frame
function update() {
        // get the ship position and it's direction vector
        var pos = ship.position;
        // default direction vector
        var dirVector = new THREE.Vector3(0,0,1);
        // apply rotation of ship
        dirVector.applyQuaternion(ship.quaternion);

        // center of the ship has relative coordinates (0,0,0)
        // start position of the ray. relative coords: (0,0,6)
        var startScale = 6;
        startVector = new THREE.Vector3(
            pos.x+startScale*dirVector.x,
            pos.y+startScale*dirVector.y,
            pos.z+startScale*dirVector.z
        );
        // end position of the ray. relative coords: (0,0,8)
        var endScale = 8;
        endVector = new THREE.Vector3(
            pos.x+endScale*dirVector.x,
            pos.y+endScale*dirVector.y,
            pos.z+endScale*dirVector.z
        );

        // update the start- and endpoint of the particle spawner
        particleRay.updateStartAndEndpoint(startVector, endVector);
        // update particles
        particleRay.update();
    }
```

Here you'll find two screenshots, one showing the correct particle ray and one showing the error.

[image: visible particle ray while camera can see origin]
[image: invisible particle ray while camera cannot see the origin]

I think the most likely cause of this problem might be a math error or an error while handling the vectors, however neither me, my tutor and anyone in my group can figure it out. I would really appreciate any kind of input on this matter. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is it just a coincidence that the particle effect seems to touch the "blue" axis?  You might also take the particle system out of the picture by using the coordinates to place a primitive following the ship.  That might help narrow down to either vector space or particle system *opportunity*.

Comment: I found out that it indeed is an error with the PointCloud particle system. I tried using another particle system we wrote (explosions), and I encountered the same error. Meaning, I can only see the explosion particles if the camera can see the coordinate origin (0,0,0). The particles themselves are generated as a THREE.Vector3 and loaded into a THREE.Geometry

Comment: @naloxx What revision of three.js are you using? Try `points.geometry.computeBoundingSphere()`.

Comment: @WestLangley I am using r71. Will try the suggested function first thing tomorrow morning. What do you think I can use the bounding sphere for?

Comment: @naloxx r.71 is more than a year old. I strongly suggest you use the latest version.

Comment: @WestLangley I updated the revision, but the error continued. We found a workaround by recreating the entire particle system in each render call. It's kind of ugly, but it works for now. I'll look into it again in a few days. Thanks for everyone's input!

Comment: For me it looks like an empty bounding box/sphere of your particle system. In this particular situation you don't need to compute it correctly so maybe just set it to some big extent (like -1000 to 1000) and see if it helped.